# How to continue animate refresh control on view changed

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, refresh, controls

I have a table in view "A" that is inside a tab bar controller. When I scroll down to reload the table refresh control start animating.When press tab bar controller going in view "B" and later go back to view "A", refresh control is visible but isn't animating.

Can someone help me? thank

```
func refresh(sender:AnyObject)
{
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in

    Call API for data
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                UPDATE UI
                refreshControl.endRefreshing()

            })
        });
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    if(requestTerminated == false)
    {
       //Continue animate refresh control somehow
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you show something that you have done in order to implement it?

Comment: edit with code @Vin

Comment: In viewDidAppear, in your if statement, try refreshControl.beginRefreshing()

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have this situation in your controller A , for example in `viewDidLoad`:

```
//global var
var refreshControl:UIRefreshControl!

self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "pull to refresh")
self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyTableViewController.pullToRefresh(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
self.tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
```

As can you see you have your `refreshControl` add as a subview to your A table controller. When you go to another controller probably you present another controller (B) and when you come back to A your refresh is freezed or stucked.

You could start `UIRefreshControl` animation on `viewWillAppear` and end it on `viewDidDisappear`. During transition save the state of refresh process to know when to show `UIRefreshControl`.

You can use a boolean like this:

```
// Refresh state
var isRefreshing = false

// Call on viewWillApper
func superviewWillApper(){
    if isRefreshing && !refreshControl.refreshing{
        startRefreshAnimation()
    }
}

// Call on viewDidDisapper
func superviewDidDisappear(){
    endRefreshAnimation(false, dataFetched: !isRefreshing)
}

func startRefreshAnimation(){
    refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
    contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -refreshControl.bounds.size.height)

    isRefreshing = true
}

//Saves state of refresh
func endRefreshAnimation(wasEmpty: Bool, dataFetched: Bool){
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    isRefreshing = !dataFetched
    if !wasEmpty{
        setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated: true)
    }else{
        setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated: false)
    }
}
```